# Tem como converter um xcarchive em xcodeworkspace?

Tags: xcode

Meu projeto `xcode` foi removido inesperadamente depois de um mês, por causa de um erro besta, e infelizmente eu não tenho um backup. Tudo que eu tenho é um arquivo `myprojectname.xcarchive`, é possível de alguma forma **descompilar** e extrair algumas classes ou códigos? Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente isso não é possível, porque o arquivo final não tem o código fonte da sua aplicação, mas você pode olhar dentro do xcarchive simplesmente segurando o control e clicando nele, no Finder, depois escolhe mostrar conteudo.